# Error while reading a folder in azure databricks which has subfolders with parquet files

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am reading a folder in adls in azure databricks which has sub folders containing parquet files.

path  - base_folder/filename/

filename has subfolders like 2020, 2021 and these folders again have subfolders for month and day.

So path for actual parquet file is like - base_folder/filename/2020/12/01/part11111.parquet.

I am getting below error if I give a base folder path.
[image]

I have tried commands in below tread as well but it is showing same error.
[Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527547/unable-to-infer-schema-for-parquet-it-must-be-specified-manually)

[image]

Please help me to read all parquet files in all sub folders in one dataframe.

Comment: Do you want to have fields containing `2020`, `12` and `01` in your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your first error: `Unable to infer schema for Parquet` usually happens when you try to read an empty directory as parquet. You can specify `*` in your path and it will go through subdirectories, take a look here: [Reading parquet files from multiple directories in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257111/reading-parquet-files-from-multiple-directories-in-pyspark).
- Second error: You are using Scala API, and the example you've provided is in Python. `DataFrameReader` API is different. Ref: [Scala - DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#load(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) - [Python - DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.load.html?highlight=dataframereader)

Try with:

```scala
spark.read.format("parquet").load(landingFolder)
```

as specified here: 
[Generic Load/Save Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks Vlad. It worked in python using *. Is there a way I can achieve this using scala.

Comment: @SharyuAadhatrao You're welcome. It should also work in scala, have you tried it? Please find examples here: [Read all files in a nested folder in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233575/read-all-files-in-a-nested-folder-in-spark), [Select files using a pattern match](https://kb.databricks.com/scala/pattern-match-files-in-path.html), also take a look at [Recursive File Lookup](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#recursive-file-lookup)

Comment: @SharyuAadhatrao If this answers your question, mark it as answered please.